# Persistence of variable value within decorator function scope in python

Tags: python, scope, decorator

Listening to Reuven M. Lerner's PyCon 2019 [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjHpMCIvwsY&t=196s) on decorators, and came across the following example of a decorating function.

```py
import time

def once_per_minute(func):
    """A decorator that prevents the decorated func 
    from being invoked more than once per minute"""

    last_invoked = 0

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal last_invoked

        elapsed_time = time.time() - last_invoked

        if elapsed_time < 60:

            raise Exception(f"Only {elapsed_time} has passed")

        last_invoked = time.time()

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

What caused confusion for me was, why does the `last_invoked` value persists with every run of the decorated function? I would assume that with every run of the decorated function, the decorator would be invoked. And every time the decorator is invoked, `last_invoked` should be reset to zero.

I looked into the documentation of the `nonlocal` keyword, and it seems to indicate that this is a variable that is bound in the nearest enclosing scope. That still does not explain why `last_invoked` is able to successfully track elapsed time.

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: "I would assume that with every run of the decorated function, the decorator would be invoked." - no, the decorator is invoked once per decorated function, immediately after the decorated function's definition.

Comment: @Boseong Choi. Of course! I should have though of it as a closure! Thank you for pointing that out.

@user2357112 supports Monica. Thank you for the answer. So does this mean that putting @once_per_minute above `def function_name():` implicitly runs the `function_name = once_per_minute(function_name)` when the decorated function is declared?